# Stop page refreshing when closing documents in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, document

We had previously used the following to stop the page refreshing when closing a document. This works fine in Sharepoint 2007 but doesn't work in 2010. Does anyone know the SP 2010 equivalent

g_varSkipRefreshOnFocus = true;

from

http://mattknott.com/content/blog/2009/08/Stop_DispEx_Redirecting.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the code in after core.js and before you start your code. Will work in a content editor webpart.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    g_varSkipRefreshOnFocus = true;
</script>
```

for testing you just add the content editor web part.

Answer (score 1):

You could also put it in windows load, did not work in document ready for me...

```
$(window).load(function () {
    console.log("g_varSkipRefreshOnFocus set to true!");
    g_varSkipRefreshOnFocus = true;    
});
```